# StaticLiveServerTestCase not logging even if Client().login works

Tags: django-testing

I'm trying to use selenium with StaticLiveServerTestCase in order to run the django server in the tests automatically.

If I'm using `Client().login` which returns `success`, I still can't pass the login page (by default, if the user is logged in it redirects to the homepage).
After some debugging it turns out that `request.user= AnonymousUser` and `User.objects.all()= QuerySet [User: USERNAME]`
It means that the user was created successfully, but is not logged in for some reason.

Here is the `code` :

```
class SeleniumTestCase(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.initialize()

def tearDown(self):
    self.selenium.quit()

def initialize(self):
    self.create_test_user()
    self.run_chrome()
    self.login()

def run_chrome(self):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    self.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10)

@staticmethod
def create_test_user():
    user = User.objects.create_superuser(
        username=USERNAME,
        email=EMAIL,
        is_active=True,
        password=PASSWORD)
    user.save()

def login(self):
    login_success = self.client.login(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
    self.assertTrue(login_success)
    self.selenium.get(self.live_server_url)

def test1(self):
    self.assertTrue(True)
```

If I sign in via the gui in my website (selenium) - I can pass the login page. But with self.client.login I can't.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I was having this problem myself and initially thought it might be an anomaly of the clicks or something in the form. Notice though that in `LiveServerTestCase.setUpClass()`, there are extra threads created, so some actions become isolated and basically, some actions will seem to have no effect on Django's back-end database.

I needed to call setUpClass() to get my fixtures, but I didn't want this thread interference just yet.

The solution for me was to make my own call to load the fixtures, then proceed with the rest of `super`'s setup:

```
class TestSalesUI(StaticLiveServerTestCase, TestCase):
    hidden_fixtures = ["bevrly/fixtures/fish_dinners.json", 
    "wine/fixtures/wine_sizes.json"]

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        for db_name in cls._databases_names(include_mirrors=False):
            try:
                call_command('loaddata', *cls.hidden_fixtures, **{
                    'verbosity': 0,
                    'commit': False,
                    'database': db_name,
                })
            except Exception:
                cls._rollback_atomics(cls.cls_atomics)
                raise
        User = get_user_model()
        cls.carpenter = User.objects.get(username="carpenter")
        # Password needs to be set now rather than in a fixture, for new hashing.
        cls.carpenter.set_password(CARPENTER_PASSWORD)
        cls.carpenter.save()
        super(TestSalesUI, cls).setUpClass()  # New threads now
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # ⏳☕
```